# setting colours for various shapes with java

Tags: java, shapes

I have made a bunch of triangles that are inside one another, I'm trying to set the color so that each triangle is a random color..How can I do this? I tried

```
g2.setColor(new Color(COLOUR,COLOUR,COLOUR));
```

and

```
COLOUR=(int)(Math.random()*256)
```

then I filled the triangle but then all the triangles end up being the same color....

```
       for ( int i=0 ; i<triangle.size() ; i++) {
            Triangle tri
            tri=triangle.get(i);
            g2.setColor(new Color(COLOR,COLOR,COLOR));
            tri.draw(g2);
      }
```

The triangle does create what i want it too, nested triangles, just cant get it colored correctly.

Comment: Please post the code so we actually have something to reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to randomize the color before you draw each triangle. If you want colors other than gray, you'll also need to initialize each component of the color (red, green, and blue) separately.

```
 int redColor,greenColor,blueColor;
 for ( int i=0 ; i<triangle.size() ; i++) {
        Triangle tri;
        tri=triangle.get(i);
        redColor=(int)(Math.random()*255);
        greenColor=(int)(Math.random()*255);
        blueColor=(int)(Math.random()*255);
        g2.setColor(new Color(redColor,greenColor,blueColor));
        tri.draw(g2);
 }
```

Hopefully this helps illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: I set my COLOR constant and expression as you have here, as a global constant so it was giving a uniform color...My problem now is that i am only gett black, white and shades of gray...

Comment: @user: I have updated my answer, I didn't realize that you wanted colors besides gray.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set new color each time you want to draw a triangle as follows:

```
g2d.setColor(aColor);
g2d.drawPolygon(); // triangle 
g2d.setColor(bColor);
g2d.drawPolygon(); // triangle
```

Comment: There is a big triangle and then within it a smaller triangle, then within that triangle a smaller triangle this continues for about 10 triangles. So each "nested" triangle should be a different color, but when I do g2.setColor(new Color(COLOR,COLOR,COLOR)); how do I color each of them?

Comment: yes, then ? each nested triangle will have a different color if you set color to the graphics g2d with setColor(newColor) right before drawing a new Triangle as i have shown in the code.

Comment: @user: You need to randomize COLOR each time as well (see my answer)

Comment: put your `COLOUR=(int)(Math.random()*256)` before you set the color. put  `COLOUR=(int)(Math.random()*256)` befor the line `g2.setColor(new Color(COLOR,COLOR,COLOR))`; and you are good to go